# How can generator of hyperboloid of 1 sheet cut principal elliptic section in 2 points

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, solid-geometry

I am a beginner in this area. So if i make wording related mistakes pls correct me.

Generator means line contained entirely in a surface. There is a problem in my textbook which goes like this --> "generator of hyperboloid of 1 sheet cuts principle elliptic section in 2 points". How can generator cuts in 2 points at principle elliptic section? Principle elliptic section means in hyperboloid, ellipse section at origin...

I am trying to visualise using this diagram... it cuts in only 1 point..
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/One-SheetedHyperboloid.html

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "elliptic section" and Googling didn't help.  Would you define it, please?

Comment: If u cut hyperboloid of 1 sheet, we get ellipse section. If that ellipse section contains origin and principle planes(xy  plane) then principle elliptic section

Comment: So it's the intersection of the hyperboloid and the $xy-$plane?

Comment: Yes ..............

Comment: Yes, it seems like any elliptic section should cut each generator in exactly one point, doesn't it?  There's something here I don't understand.

Comment: @saulspatz pls see the image i have pasted the problem

Comment: This is a doubly-ruled surface—there are two lines through each point that lie on the surface. The snippet of text that you’ve shown consistently uses the singular “generator” with plural verbs, so I would hazard a guess that the text uses this term for the *pair* of lines. Look back to where the term “generator” is introduced in this book.

Comment: @amd Yes u r right! it should be rephrased as pair of generators from P cutting principle ellipse section at A and B. Then we get PAB triangle. PA and PM are generators of opposite system from P ...
THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this text uses the singular “generator” to mean the pair of lines through a point on a doubly-ruled surface. This grammatically singular-number word is consistently used in a plural context in the text snippet that you’ve provided. I expect that this will be the case if you go back to where it introduces the term “generator” and examine its definition.